# How can I find width and height of a chrome extension popup?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am making a simple practice Chrome app that shows a popup with width and height of the popup.

Visual:

[image: intent]

> clearly these dimensions are wrong.

I tried multiple things all of them giving wrong dimensions of the popup window:

1. window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight
2. window.outerWidth, window.outerHeight
3. document.body.clientWidth, document.body.clientHeight
4. document.body.offsetWidth, document.body.offsetHeight

Here are the addon files:

**manifest.json**:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "minimalChromePopupAddon",
    "version": "0",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>  
    <pre id="infoSection">hi</pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js (See snippet below if you want a traditional version of this code)

```
(() => {
    'use strict';

    /* gets {"width": 0, "height": 0} */
    const getWindowSize1 = () => {
        return {
            width: window.innerWidth,
            height: window.innerHeight
        };
    };

    /* gets {"width": 1366, "height": 740} */
    const getWindowSize2 = () => {
        return {
            width: window.outerWidth,
            height: window.outerHeight
        };
    };

    /* gets {"width": 30, "height": 35} */
    const getWindowSize3 = () => {
        return {
            width: document.body.clientWidth,
            height: document.body.clientHeight
        };    
    }

    /* gets {"width": 14, "height": 15} */
    const getWindowSize4 = () => {
        return {
            width: document.body.offsetWidth,
            height: document.body.offsetHeight
        };         
    };

    window.onload = () => {     
        const infoSection = document.getElementById('infoSection');   
        const info = getWindowSize4();                  

        infoSection.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(info, null, 4);
    };
})();
```

popup.js (simplified to be more traditional javascript)

```
/* gets {"width": 0, "height": 0} */
function getWindowSize1() {
    var ret = {
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight
    };

    return ret;
}

/* gets {"width": 1366, "height": 740} */
function getWindowSize2() {
    var ret = {
        width: window.outerWidth,
        height: window.outerHeight
    };

    return ret;
}

/* gets {"width": 30, "height": 35} */
function getWindowSize3() {
    var ret = {
        width: document.body.clientWidth,
        height: document.body.clientHeight
    };    

    return ret;
}

/* gets {"width": 14, "height": 15} */
function getWindowSize4() {
    var ret = {
        width: document.body.offsetWidth,
        height: document.body.offsetHeight
    };    

    return ret;
}

function loadListener(event) {
    window.removeEventListener('load', loadListener);
    var infoSection = document.getElementById('infoSection');   
    var info = getWindowSize4();                  

    infoSection.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(info, null, 4);
}

window.addEventListener('load', loadListener);
```

Can somebody tell me how to get the dimensions of the popup in pixels, or explain why this cannot be done?

Thanks ahead of time.

**Possible Answer**:

Displaying the window size inside the window changes the window size to fit the text being displayed, which in turn no longer corresponds to the text being shown... The issue is that

**Solution**:

**popup.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <style>
/* make sure that adding text to info section does not alter viewport size. */
#infoSection {
    width: 150px;
    height: 80px;
    overflow: scroll;
}    
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>  
    <pre id="infoSection">hi</pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
(() => {
    'use strict';

    window.onload = () => {
        const infoSection = document.getElementById('infoSection');   
        const info = {
            width: document.body.clientWidth,
            height: document.body.clientHeight
        };    

        infoSection.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(info, null, 4); 
    };    
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

Adding text to `#infoSection` changes the size of viewport because `#infoSection` expands to accomodate the information being placed into it. One way to remedy the issue is to make `#infoSection` fixed size with scrollbars, this way adding text to it does not make it resize and change the viewport.

**Visual**:

[image: visual]

**popup.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <style>
/* make sure that adding text to info section does not alter viewport size. */
#infoSection {
    width: 150px;
    height: 80px;
    overflow: scroll;
}    
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>  
    <pre id="infoSection">hi</pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
(() => {
    'use strict';

    window.onload = () => {
        const infoSection = document.getElementById('infoSection');   
        const info = {
            width: document.body.clientWidth,
            height: document.body.clientHeight
        };    

        infoSection.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(info, null, 4); 
    };    
})();
```

Comment: Yes, the popup is dynamically sized. Isn't it, like, obvious?

Comment: Yes, It is but it took me a surprisingly long time to realize this was the case. It's why I make experiments like these, to stop making silly mistakes like these and practice recognizing them quicker.

Comment: Also popup sizing has some non-obvious behaviors. For example, a popup with a longish h1 block expands only to a certain point and then carries to the next line, so i've come to an impression that it's a good habit to fix your window viewport to a preferred size once you know what that preferred size is, but until then it's not unusual for non-obvious things to happen.